# Twilio doesn't call my TwiML instruction url

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I'm using Twilio to send a verification code through voice call. I've used this tutorial to write the code:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/implement-account-verification-login-by-phone-laravel-php

So, that's basically the code. My phone rings and I get the "You have a test account, press any key to run your code" message, but when I press a key, it hangs up on me and my code is never called.

```php
public function sendVerificationCodeThroughCall($mobile)
{
    $code = $this->createMobileCode($mobile);

    $client = new Client(config('services.twilio.sid'), config('services.twilio.auth_token'));

    $client->calls->create(
        $mobile,
        config('services.twilio.phone_number'),
        ["url" => route('voice-code.build', $code)]
    );
}
```

```php
public function buildVoiceCode($code)
{
    Log::debug('Twilio called to say: ' . $code);

    $code = $this->splitCode($code);
    $response = new VoiceResponse();
    $response->say("Salaam. This is your verification code: {$code}. I repeat, {$code}.");
    echo $response;
}

protected function splitCode($code)
{
    return implode('.', str_split($code));
}
```

Comment: Do you see the TwiML execute in the call logs (clicking the call SID a d viewing the request inspector output? Does Debugger report any errors?

Comment: @Alan The call request details has my Url, but it doesn't say anything about TwiML. When I curl my url it runs fine, but Twilio never seems to send a request to my webhook.

Comment: Did you wait for the Press Any Key Prompt to fully play out before pressing the key?

Comment: @Alan Yes, tried all possible timings

Comment: Hey there, @mokhosh. I'm the lead PHP author for Twilio tutorials. Any chance of sharing a link to your complete code? That way I can take a better look to see what might be going wrong?

Comment: @MatthewSetter I'm no longer working on that project. It was more than 3 years ago :)